# Set transaction only one time in all entity DAL classes

Tags: c#

I have multiple DAL classes which perform CRUD and take an transaction object.
I want to assign transaction object only to one class, so it's set into all DAL classes..

```
Public Class Employee{
    Transactions trans = null
  public List<Emp> Save(){
    // Transaction Will  Use There So It can Save 
   }
}

Public Class Customer{
    Transactions trans = null
  public List<Cst> Save(){
    // Transaction Will  Use There So It can Save 
   }
}

Public Static Void Main(String[] args ){
SqlTransaction trans = db.BeginTransactions();
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.trans;
Customer cst = new Customer();
cst.trans;

}
```

In the code above you can see all Instances I have to pass to transaction object. Every instance of DAL I create like Shop, Company etc..
I want to get rid off this.

Comment: You can get rid of both transactions and the DAL classes if you use an ORM like EF Core *and* gain disconnected operation. Long-lived transactions seriously harm performance. There's no reason to use data-access objects like the ones. you show here. In fact, since at least 1998 all Microsoft data access technologies can work in a disconnected, batched  manner, requiring transactions only when saving changes.

Comment: You can use [implicit transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope) through a TransactionScope. All operations performed inside this scope automatically participate in the same transaction. You'd still have the same performance and concurrency issues though.